# Where to see LDAP authentication logs for pgadmin4?

Tags: ldap, pgadmin

I am running pgadmin4 version 5.3 on a CentOS 7 server trying to configure LDAP / LDAPS authentication. It is not working, however I cannot see where to view the logs regarding the error. I have checked the apache error log, and pgadmin4 log file. I have adjusted logging settings in the config.py file to be DEBUG, but still I cannot see any log details regarding the errors.

Can someone tell me how to adjust settings for pgadmin4 to properly log LDAP authentication information, and in what logs that info would be?

Comment: I see it is a pretty old thread but I'm in the same situation. Is there any way to see the actual error of the auth flow?
I have set CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL and FILE_LOG_LEVEL to 10 (debug), and DEBUG to True, but I still don't see any useful messages in the log.

There is only one line, saying the request has been forwarded:

    "POST /authenticate/login HTTP/1.1" 302 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"

Comment: I never found a way to see more log information either. Ultimately I had to rely on what little logs were available on the server-side, and use trial and error with the pgadmin configurations to get it working.